# Using phonegap for send SMS

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am new in phonegap. I try install last version phonegap via cmd, the phonegap installed but i don't see cordova 3.4.jar for add to my library. I try build with cmd but i can't, i give error in "phonegap platform add android" , the error is "platform add android" is not a node in my directory. i searched but i can't solve this. anyway, i forgot phonegap 3.4 :(

i get phonegap 2.9 and unzip in development folder and i copy cordova2.9.jar to my project. I write a page with javascript and html for show information about device and i can send sms. but when i press on button for send sms, sms not send and i show alert fail, i guess, the program dont call sendSMS to java file.but i don't know why? and how Can i solve this? and the my question is, the problem may be from install phonegap 3.4 and use cordova 2.9?

Thanks for advise and sorry for my long message

Comment: After install you have to update platform as well with this command "cordova platform update android"

Comment: I see android platfrom is not installed. Why?

Comment: Do you even have anything in platforms folder?

Comment: Do you maybe have this code somewhere public so I can check whats wrong with it. As there might be so many factors its easier to manually check whats wrong. Or if this is private you can contact me via email.

Comment: Follow the following link. It worked for me:http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/ This works for PhoneGap 3.x

Comment: Thanks.Where is platforms folder? I think, i set wrong environment variable for java and etc. Can you say to me, what and with witch set variable in enviroment?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using  PhoneGap 3.4 use [following instruction](http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/).

After that use these plugin for https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin for sending SMS from phonegap 3.4 application.

I got success for sending SMS.

Comment: hi , iam getting really confused, how to use this plugin in my project, at  least can u help me to test this plugin. im using telerik app builder . should i import the whole plugin as it is and try.

Comment: Plese follow instruction which is given on link:- https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin for use this plugin in your project and sorry for that i don't have any idea about "telerik app builder" because i try that plugin in my phonegap application.